# Cbr 150r 2016 model thailand version

Tags: motorcycle

I have Honda CBR 150R 2016 model Thailand ( sports spirit) 
I am useing caltex havoline 10w30 minarel engine oil.

I want to switch to 100% synthetic.
I run my bike 2045km.

In my region there is no 10w30 synthetic engine oil.

I can get Mobil1, shell, motul, yamalube synthetic oil in my area of 10w40 grade.
But here is 10w30 semi synthetic by motul.

I am in confustion do i shift to 10w40 from 10w30 ? It will harm my bikes engine?

Thanks for your patience for reading my text.

Greetings from Bangladesh.

Comment: Not familiar with your bike, but does the engine oil also lubricate the transmission and clutch?  If so, you need to use an oil made for that - you shouldn't just grab some oil made for a car.

Comment: I would use the oil the manufacturer recommends, and change it frequently.  I do not see much benefit switching to synthetic, which will cost more and potentially cause problems if the oil is shared with the transmission and friction surfaces as @JPhi1618 mentioned.